# Shell operator "||" did not work as expected?

Tags: shell, date, curl

I am trying to get the file time from the HTTP Header with the following command.

```
curl -sLI http://sgp-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin | grep -i '^Last-Modified' | cut -c16- | date -f- '+%F %T'
```

Under normal circumstances, it can return query results.

If the query fails due to network problems, it will return null.

I want to return the current system time when the query fails. So I use the shell operator "||", which is used as follows.

```
curl -sLI http://sgp-ping.vultr.com/xxx.bin | grep -i '^Last-Modified' | cut -c16- | date -f- '+%F %T' || date '+%F %T'
```

But it doesn't work as expected, what's wrong with it?

Any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: `false | true | true | true || echo hmm...` - It's a [pipeline](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02_01)

Comment: @jhnc Oh, now I understand. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: If bash, there is `PIPESTATUS` array. For POSIX shell, It's difficult.

Comment: @Lorraine1996 : `date -f- '+%F %T'` is expected to have exit code 0, Therefore `date '+%F %T'` won't be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a script you can deal with it via `$?` just need to allow for it.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

doTheCurl() {
    curl -v -sLI -o /dev/null "$1" 2>&1 | grep -i '< Last-Modified:'
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && date '+%F %T'
}


doTheCurl "http://sgp-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin"

doTheCurl "http://non-sgp-ping.vultra.com/xxx.bin"
```

Gives this [I ignored extracting / formatting - but you can see the results are different because they came from different paths.].

```
< Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Oct 2020 18:06:00 GMT
2021-03-12 16:24:19
```

The first one fails because the grep doesn't match anything - so it then gives the date.
You can do whatever you like - pipe thru sed or whatever after.